# Material settings is changed to 2d animation mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine

After few hours of working i see that i cant find one of material in material list.
If i select object with that material i can see strange settings tab, how can it happen and how i can fix that material?

on picture "cloth" material with default settings tab and "metall" with strange settings tab looks like from 2d animation mode

[image]

Comment: Looks like the object with the "metall" shader is a Grease Pencil Object, not a mesh object. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/materials/grease_pencil_shader.html

Comment: No, its standard mesh object=(